# Js Script doesn't work Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a script that work perfectly on Chrome Firefox and Edge but not on IE.

The error I have is : Unexpected token var clearContent = () => {
Whys is it an error fir internet explorer but not for the others brower.

```
var clearContent = () => {
var allDistricts = document.querySelectorAll(".district");
allDistricts.forEach(item => {
    item.style.display = "none";
});
```

Thanks for help

Comment: What version of IE? I'm guessing it doesn't support arrow functions.

Comment: The version is Internet explorer 11. I will try it.